# Consultar categorías de página de facebok en español con Api Graph desde Android

Tags: android, facebook-api

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en android con la Api Graph de facebook y me encontré con el siguiente problema:

Necesito consultar la lista de categorías de las páginas de facebook, revisando su documentación [categoría de páginas](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-category/) pude consultarlas, el problema es que los nombres están en Inglés, mi pregunta sería si es posible traducirlas al español
enviando algún parámetro o similar?

Código:

```
 
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
      accessToken,"/fb_page_categories",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
     @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
   });

request.executeAsync();
```

Respuesta:

```
 
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Interest",
      "api_enum": "ACTIVITY_GENERAL",
      "fb_page_categories": [
        {
          "name": "Literary Arts",
          "api_enum": "LITERARY_ARTS",
          "id": "856055631167537"
        },
        {
          "name": "Performance Art",
          "api_enum": "PERFORMANCE_ART",
          "id": "756092301147942"
        },
....
```